# MSGBox quando não acha a procura não aparece

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

O MSGBox em negrito não funciona. Ou qdo ele funciona não pega os dados localizado.

Sub MSIAPE()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

```
Dim MSIAPE As String
Dim Celula As Range
Dim Valor
Dim Assunto As String
Dim Processo As String
Dim Error As String

MSIAPE = InputBox("Digite a matrícula SIAPE:")
        
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Impressão").Range("B13").Value = MSIAPE
    
For Each Celula In Sheets("Funcionario").UsedRange
    If Celula.Value = MSIAPE Then
        If Celula.Offset(0, 6).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "O campo Processo não pode ficar vazio", 48, "Campo em branco"
    flag = 0
            Processo = InputBox("Digite o Processo:")
            Sheets("Impressão").[b7].Value = Processo
            Else
                Sheets("Impressão").[b7].Value = Celula.Offset(0, 6).Value
        End If
        If Celula.Offset(0, 6).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "O campo Assunto não pode ficar vazio", 48, "Campo em branco"
            flag = 0
            Assunto = InputBox("Digite o Assunto:")
            Sheets("Impressão").[b8].Value = Assunto
            Else
                Sheets("Impressão").[b8].Value = Celula.Offset(0, 8).Value
        End If
            Sheets("Impressão").[b12].Value = Celula.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Sheets("Impressão").[b14].Value = Celula.Offset(0, 7).Value
            Sheets("Impressão").[b15].Value = Celula.Offset(0, 2).Value & " a " & Celula.Offset(0, 3).Value
        If Celula.Value <> MSIAPE Then
            **MsgBox "Esta Matrícula SIAPE esta errada ou não existe!"**
Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next

Sheets("Impressão").Select
     Range("b13").Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Olá.

Não olhei todo o código e sim onde você está com problema.
Segue correção:

```
Sub MSIAPE()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim MSIAPE As String
Dim Celula As Range
Dim Valor
Dim Assunto As String
Dim Processo As String
Dim Error As String

MSIAPE = InputBox("Digite a matrícula SIAPE:")
        
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Impressão").Range("B13").Value = MSIAPE
    
For Each Celula In Sheets("Funcionario").UsedRange
    If Celula.Value = MSIAPE Then
        If Celula.Offset(0, 6).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "O campo Processo não pode ficar vazio", 48, "Campo em branco"
    flag = 0
            Processo = InputBox("Digite o Processo:")
            Sheets("Impressão").[b7].Value = Processo
            Else
                Sheets("Impressão").[b7].Value = Celula.Offset(0, 6).Value
        End If
        If Celula.Offset(0, 6).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "O campo Assunto não pode ficar vazio", 48, "Campo em branco"
            flag = 0
            Assunto = InputBox("Digite o Assunto:")
            Sheets("Impressão").[b8].Value = Assunto
            Else
                Sheets("Impressão").[b8].Value = Celula.Offset(0, 8).Value
        End If
        Sheets("Impressão").[b12].Value = Celula.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Sheets("Impressão").[b14].Value = Celula.Offset(0, 7).Value
        Sheets("Impressão").[b15].Value = Celula.Offset(0, 2).Value & " a " & Celula.Offset(0, 3).Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Esta Matrícula SIAPE esta errada ou não existe!"
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Sheets("Impressão").Select
Range("b13").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

O que acontece que a lógica está errada.
Se `Celula.Value = MSIAPE` não será `Celula.Value <> MSIAPE`.
Sendo assim, se não for igual, será diferente.
Essas duas condições são opostas, se não for de uma forma, com certeza será de outra.

```
if Celula.Value = MSIAPE THEN
    ...
else
    MsgBox "Esta Matrícula SIAPE esta errada ou não existe!"
    Exit For
end if
```

OBS. Desculpe pela forma de me expressar. Espero que tenha entendido.

Só um detalhe, sempre que desligar a atualização de tela no inicio:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Ligue novamente no final:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```